# how to access a file from USB through Native Client

Tags: google-nativeclient

I am trying to access contents of USB through native client using URLloader API however I get an error message while I call the 'Open() function' and error code is -7 ( Indicates failure due to insufficient privileges. PP_ERROR_NOACCESS = -7).Can you suggest me any alternative way of loading file from USB through NaCl and is there any support in NaCl or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "from USB"? What is the URL you are using?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to access contents inside a pen drive (usb flash drive)
I am fetching the URL by an inbuilt plugin API for the device I am using (smart TV). The URLs I receive from the plugin api (eg. /dtv/usb/sda1/abc.jpg) get loaded through JS or flash but through NaCl, I am not able to access. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the file in JavaScript, tat least sending the file (via postMessage) to your nacl application should be possible.